# Is there a way to reconstruct a tuple to a compatible class?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-7.0

Given a tuple (int, string) v and a class C { int, string }, in C#7, implementing C's Deconstruct(out int k, out string v) would allow the ff.:

```
C c = new C();
(int k, string v) = c;
```

But the reverse seems unsupported, such that the tuple can be "reconstructed" to a compatible class:

```
(int k, string v) vt = (1, "one");
C c = vt;
```

I'm thinking it should be supported if C has a constructor that "matches" C's Deconstruct() parameters:

```
class C
{
    public C(int k, string v)
    ...
}
```

Is it possible? Available? Planned? I can't seem to find anything about it. Or perhaps a re-usable code/trick to "Reconstruct"?

Comment: That looks to be "duck typing", which they haven't supported because of the myriad of issues that can come from that freedom. It's possible that's changed in C#7, though I would be surprised.

Comment: I don't think there is such a feature and i doubt it's very useful. What if a class has 2 int and 3 string propperties. How often you would need this feature? Why you can't use the readable and safe approach: `C c = new C { IntPropName=tuple.Item1, StringPropName=tuple.Item2 };`?

Comment: Does deconstruct even use a tuple? Sure, it uses tuple-like syntax, but: there is no tuple there... it deconstructs into variables (and those variables need names - the code at the top of the question doesn't compile - needs to be `(int a, string b)` IIRC)

Comment: Which suggests that the properties are public. If C's k and v can only be valued through C's constructor, might be OK if the "reconstruction" would always go through C's construction routine.

Comment: @krillgar it wouldn't be "duck typing" because there'd still be the need of implementing this behavior in `C` (same as `Deconstruct`); its not as if it were a default behavior that should work as long as the type structures are compatible.The required behavior is easily implemented via an implicit operator.

Comment: @InBetween Interesting! (Especially your answer.) I haven't gotten too far into the C#7 stuff, and meant more that it *seemed* like duck typing. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: *Constructors* are the equivalent to what you ask. You can't just reconstruct a class from some property types without some very strong assumptions, eg no initialization logic outside some default constructor, ordering of fields, etc. That's what record types in F# and hopefully, C# 8 will provide

Comment: @InBetween suggested a solution that may permit it, for as long as it is explicitly allowed for the class. Adding an implicit operator is as deliberate as implementing Deconstruct() -- it is allowed because you allowed it. Wondering if it can be part of language/compiler to automatically emit the implicit operator code if Deconstruct()/constructor conditions are met...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Of course you can. Simply implement an implicit operator:

```
public static implicit operator C((int, string) t) 
    => new C(t.Item1, t.Item2);
```

There is no need of some special `Reconstruct` method because the language already provides the necessary tools to achieve the behavior you want.

Comment: Which limits to 2 values/properties. A "generic" reconstruction, like opposite of Deconstruct(), might need language/compiler level support. krillgar called it "duck typing", though.

Comment: @EdmundoMendiola I'm not following you. You *need* to implement `Deconstruct` too, its not built into *any* `ValueTuple`. The only compiler support is a convenient syntax which is not needed in the opposite direction because you really are dealing with a tuple and a good old implicit coversion which the compiler understands perfectly well.

Comment: @EdmundoMendiola My "duck typing" comment was intended mostly at your first example of "Well it should just work because I can see that it walks like a `C` and talks like a `C`. I know as a human that it is a `C`." InBetween here is showing that you *can* do what you want, but nothing that you're expecting to happen is naturally built into the language, though they give you the tools to do what you're doing in specific situations. A completely generic solution (I'm assuming using something similar to `params`) *probably* isn't available, but I'll defer to InBetween.

Comment: Yes. As described in my question, it is given that C must have Deconstruct() implemented. If I'm following you right, if I want "reconstruction", then I should likewise implement an implicit operator for C. I was thinking if reconstruction can be "automatic" like part of the language/syntax for as long as C has a constructor that reciprocates its Deconstruct(). It was done for Deconstruct(), so...

Comment: @EdmundoMendiola no, there is not, and it wouldn't be convenient either; how you deconstruct your type is not necessarily how you  instantiate it.  Some properties might not be set in the constructor via an argument at all, they could be evaluated based on other arguments supplied to the constructor. You can have, I'd actually say you *will* have, most of the time, a structure mismatch between the deconstructed tuple and the constructor.

Comment: @EdmundoMendiola Also, `Deconstruct` can be *overloaded* so you can deconstruct any given type to as many different tuples as you'd like if you really wanted to. Because `Deconstruct`'s only purpose is to deconstruct into tuples, you are free to do what you want. The *constructor's mission* is to *construct new instances, not reconstruct tuples*; those two things can be *radically different*. Therefore,  having an independent equivalent way to do the reconstruction seems the reasonable option, and implicit operators provide just that.

Comment: Good point @InBetween. Though if it can be detected which Deconstruct() has a matching constructor, then it will be the only one that the compiler will automatically allow/include your implicit operator for.

Comment: Thus, if the compiler will do so, it is still a constructor thing as your implicit operator solution suggests. Since the creation of C is via its constructor anyway, C c = (1, "one"); can be a deliberate intention, if the language/compiler will allow it. Syntactic sugar? .Net allowed for a lot of syntactic shortcuts. What can go wrong with adding @InBetween's implicit operator solution to the mix?

Answer (score 15):

There is a very subtle distinction between:

```
(int, string) x = c; // tuple assignment
(int a, string b) x = c; // tuple assignment with member aliases
```

and

```
(int a, string b) = c; // deconstruction
```

Importantly your code is **neither of these**, so won't compile - but from the context it is clear that you're talking about deconstruction syntax, so I'm assuming the bottom form.

The deconstruction syntax (the one ***without a name after the tuple-like expression***) doesn't actually create a tuple. In fact, it requires names **in the pair**:

```
(int a, string b) = c;
```

or:

```
var (a, b) = c;
```

This is *not* a tuple, but is convenience syntax for:

```
c.Deconstruct(out int a, out string b);
```

So: at no point are tuples involved (although oddly the `System.ValueTuple` reference is still required).

The reverse operation - passing multiple variables into a constructor - is: a regular constructor. Note that you couldn't pass the "tuple-like thing" *anywhere*, because *it doesn't have a name - it isn't a local*.

Comment: @InBetween's suggestion seems like a possibility, though should be implemented explicitly along with Deconstruct(). I understand what you're saying. I'm thinking it would be nice to have reconstruction to be compiler/language supported for as long as a constructor is present that reciprocates Deconstruct(). No topic like this in dotnet/roslyn, or perhaps I missed it?

Comment: @EdmundoMendiola No there is not, and I'd be very much surprised if it ever was. As commented elsewhere, constructors are meant to construct instances, not reconstruct tuples. Those are two very different beasts, conflating them is not a good idea at all.

Comment: @Marc-Gravell, I edited the question to reflect your correction (yes, bottom form). Thanks!

Comment: After much self-deliberation, I agree that a syntax like this C c = (1, "one"); should NOT be natively supported. Putting all points together, it all boils down to the fact there is no limit to how Deconstruct() can be implemented. To support the syntax should be deliberate as suggested by @InBetween, thereby allowed only because the internal implementation of Deconstruct() is known and that there is no assumption. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

There is already a way to do the opposite of deconstructing (ie. taking some object apart to its component elements). It is "constructing" (ie. making an object from components). The most straightforward way to do the opposite of `(x, y) = c;` is to do `c = new C(x, y);`.

There is a candidate feature that is being considered to simplify syntax like `c = new C(x, y);` down to `c = new (x, y);` by omitting/inferring  the type of the constructor. It's called target-typed construction ([1]).

If you want to propose some other way of constructing, it would be important to show the value of the new feature. The [csharplang repo](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang) is a good place to discuss such ideas and get a feel for the community and the team's feedback.

Removing the `new` may be discussed, but I don't think it's a good idea. For instance, in `(x, y, z) = (a, b);` should the compiler consider constructing a type `C` from two elements a and b, then invoking the `Deconstruct` method with three elements that it may find on `C`? You can see how treating deconstructions as conversions (that can chain and appear in a number of places in the code) leads to combinatorial explosion.

[1]: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/100 (the link tracks this candidate feature and has a link to most recent LDM notes, which are succinct as the language feature was not discussed in details).

Comment: Thank you! This is fantastic to know. There is really a discussion about it and it's even more advanced than I thought. Even has a name for it: target-type construction. You just made my day!

Comment: This is just syntactic sugar to simplify calling a constructor, it has nothing to do with tuples. These are regular constructor calls. Convenient when constructing in place objects in method calls for instance (and little else unless I'm missing something), but again, I fail to see the relation with tuples and the question at hand.

Comment: Edited to add a link to the csharp language repo. Feel free to modify if you don't like my edit.

Comment: My fat fingers. I still think @InBetween provided the most reasonable answer. I agree with all points raised. The syntactic sugar described in my question may not be safe as a language/compiler feature. It is unsafe and assumes too much. To allow it, and to use it should be explicit, deliberate and, in good faith, respectful of true representations. It can also conflict with the target-typed construction idea which also raises the conversion chain problem.